# .Net 4.0 crashes in clr.dll on Windows Server 2008 x86

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, crash, windows-server-2008, clr

We have a Windows Application that runs day in day out at several locations. Now though they've started crashing, they don't even generate an error on crash (should be catched by NLOG), they just stop suddenly. The only logs of the crash I can find is in the system event logger where I get 2 error logs:

```
Faulting application myapp.exe, version 1.0.0.0, time stamp 0x53f3377c, faulting module clr.dll, version 4.0.30319.2034, time stamp 0x52ccfa2b, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x0000ee9f, process id 0x%9, application start time 0x%10.
```

and

```
The process was terminated due to an internal error in the .NET Runtime at IP 6D09EE9F (6D090000) with exit code 80131506.
```

These are the descriptions in the event viewer (I can post the entire event log if it would help).

I hope someone knows how to get rid of these (I'm sick of getting calls in the night).

Comment: That's ExecutionEngineException, immediately crashes your program.  Typically caused by corruption of the GC heap.  Typically caused by bad pinvoke code or misbehaving unmanaged code.  You are going to keep getting called when you document your question so poorly.  Call Microsoft Support for help, they'll hold you by the hand getting this problem resolved.

Comment: This might not always be due to bad P/Invoke code, [Microsoft has a bug on file with clr.dll that caused an Access Violation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2640103/fix-faulting-module-name-clr.dll-error-message-when-you-run-a-microsoft-.net-framework-4-based-application). Unfortunately I'm not sure how somebody would know if they had this issue because the event images don't seem to be loading; for future readers I'd recommend updating .NET if you're still on .NET 4 for whatever reason.